# Why are there multiple instances of Logic Apps running?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My Logic App has one trigger. When it fires, 3 instances of the Logic App run and all perform the same operations, leading to duplication in the database.

[Multiple concurrent instances in groups of three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0OAn.png)

This is the Logic App orchestration:

[Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZjik.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved by making Recurrence single instance only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgf0e.png)

Comment: You should not have to do this, can you email me (Derek.Li (at) microsoft.com your subscription Id and workflow name so we can look into this?

Comment: Hey @Jarrod , i have the same issue! Cannot find the option of `Single Instance  Only` ,but having the 'Degree of Parellelism` set to `1` , still there are total 2 instances of my app running! Not sure why this is happening @Derek Li !

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue: 15 instances started. In my case, I actually did have 15 messages to process but my email client didn't give a clue :)

But for the other cases, here's some background information on concurrence control which I think replaced the "single instance" option:
https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/logic-apps-concurrency-control/